# poetry + watchmedo + uwsgi: unrecognized arguments

Tags: python, uwsgi, python-poetry

I have a uWSGI application that I want to monitor with watchmedo, and is under a poetry environment.

Unfortunately, the following does not work:

```
poetry run watchmedo auto-restart --directory=./ --pattern="*.py;*.yml;*.html" --recursive -- uwsgi --ini=uwsgi.ini
```

This command raises:

```
watchmedo: error: unrecognized arguments: --ini=uwsgi.ini
```

it seems that poetry is incapable of understanding that I'm passing parameters to uwsgi, not to watchmedo. I tried multiple permutations of this command and I could not get it to work. What am I missing? Even running this as `poetry run bash -c` still raises the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The package [`watchmedog`/`watchmedo`](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) uses the module [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) to process the CLI arguments. Unfortunately, IMHO, it incorrectly processes *all* arguments in one step instead of processing only its arguments and passing the remaining arguments to the called command.

Besides that, it is possible to work around this issue using the pseudo-argument `--` twice in the command. You need to use a `--` right after the last `watchmedo`'s argument and another `--` before the command's arguments.

Instead of:

```sh
poetry run watchmedo auto-restart -d . -p '*.py' -R -- uwsgi --ini=uwsgi.ini
```

use:

```sh
poetry run watchmedo auto-restart -d . -p '*.py' -R -- uwsgi -- --ini=uwsgi.ini
```

Comment: This does not seem to work correctly: the first time it runs, it fails with a KeyboardInterrupt automatically (despite no keyboardinterrupt being passed to it). It would work fine for uwsgi in this specific case, because it hard crashes and then boots up again due to watchmedo, but for systems like celery it gets stuck in an infinite loop of aborting.

Comment: It should be something not specifically related to that because despite the example using uwsgi I am using the same structure to run celery on my current project and it is working properly:

```
poetry run watchmedo auto-restart -R -d '...' -p '*.py' -- celery -- --app=$(APP) worker
```